# How to set my own root token in HashiCorp Vault Docker Compose file

Tags: docker, docker-compose, hashicorp-vault

With my current Vault docker compose file, I'm not able to login with my token which I've set as part of my docker compose file. When Vault container starts up - it provides his own root token to authenticate in vault server. And this  keep on change whenever we bring up new container and developer has to note it down from the console every-time and use that token to login in Vault.

Instead of that I want to set as part of docker compose file - How can I do that.

Please find my docker compose file below:

```
version: '3'
services:
  myvault:
        image: vault
        container_name: myvault
        ports:
          - "192.168.99.100:8200:8200"
        environment:
           VAULT_SERVER: "http://192.168.99.100:8200"
           TOKEN: mysuper-secret-vault-token
        volumes:
          - ./file:/vault/file:rw
          - ./config:/vault/config:rw
        cap_add:
          - IPC_LOCK
```

Answer (score 4):

First of all, root token should not be used for authentication for security reason as it can do **anything**.

> [the Vault team recommends](https://www.vaultproject.io/docs/concepts/tokens.html#root-tokens) that root tokens are only used for just enough initial setup (usually, setting up auth methods and policies necessary to allow administrators to acquire more limited tokens) or in emergencies, and are revoked immediately after they are no longer needed. If a new root token is needed, the operator generate-root command and associated API endpoint can be used to generate one on-the-fly.

Now, regarding root token creation, from the [vault documentation](https://www.vaultproject.io/docs/concepts/tokens.html#root-tokens):

> there are only three ways to create root tokens:
>
> - The initial root token generated at vault init time -- this token has no expiration
> - By using another root token; a root token with an expiration cannot create a root token that never expires
> - By using vault operator generate-root (example) with the permission of a quorum of unseal key holders

---

For your case, you may consider  using using some other [auth methods](https://www.vaultproject.io/docs/auth/index.html) instead of token authentication, for example, the [Userpass Auth Method](https://www.vaultproject.io/docs/auth/userpass.html).

Userpass Auth will allow you to setup the same pair of username/password for the same user role. You may create some script that will enable this auth mechanism and setup users for each initial setup of your server.

Answer (score 4):

@Learn Java You can create your own root token by passing **VAULT_DEV_ROOT_TOKEN_ID** in environment as below, but one thing to remember is this only works when you are using vault in development mode, **not at all recommended** for production.

Visit https://www.vaultproject.io/docs/commands/server.html

```
version: '3'
services:
myvault:
    image: vault
    container_name: myvault
    ports:
      - 8200:8200
    environment:
       VAULT_SERVER: "http://127.0.0.1:8200"
       VAULT_DEV_ROOT_TOKEN_ID: "my-token"
```

Answer (score 0):

Following along with hvac documentation ( https://hvac.readthedocs.io/en/stable/overview.html#initialize-the-client )

I was able to get root token with the following python script:

```
import hvac
from icecream import ic
client = hvac.Client(url='http://localhost:8200')
ic(client.is_authenticated())
ic(client.sys.is_initialized())

shares = 5
threshold = 3

result = client.sys.initialize(shares, threshold)
ic(result['root_token'])
ic(result['keys'])

ic(client.sys.is_initialized())
```